# authentication is disabled - How to verify whether this is local disabling or Active Directory disabling

Tags: user-account, active-directory

I have a Macbook Pro that uses ActiveDirectory for authentication. However, when I go to System Preferences to make changes, it gives me the following error:

[image]

If I run `dscl . -read /Users/<username> AuthenticationAuthority`, everything seems to be ok but I think that the local password has become out of sync with ActiveDirectory.

Is there a way to tell my local account to resync with ActiveDirectory?

Or is there a different interpretation of what might be going on?

I tried this soln (seen here https://www.reddit.com/r/macsysadmin/comments/ahhpdd/password_mismatch/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) `root> Sysadminctl -secureTokenOff <username> -password <AD-pwd> interactive` but am not able to disable my own SecureToken.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue on a M1 mac and something was wrong with the secure token.  Recreating the token per this JAMF post fixed it for the user.  You'll need a second account with a secure token for this to work.

https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/softwareupdate-is-trying-to-authenticate-user-authentication-is/m-p/245357

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenOff <username> -password - -adminUser <adminusername> -adminPassword -
sysadminctl -secureTokenOn <username> -password - -adminUser <adminusername> -adminPassword -
diskutil apfs UpdatePreboot /
```

I just had the issue on another M1 mac and the following commands fixed it

```
pwpolicy -u <username> -disableuser
pwpolicy -u <username> -enableuser
```